# Ruby Replace First Appearance of A Pattern

Tags: ruby, regex

can any one help me with replace patterns in ruby?

I have a string like this:

```
abc <abc> def "<def>"
```

Rule is:  to replace anything with <> with an empty string, but do not replace those with "<>". replace `<abc>` by an empty string `''`, and leave `"<def>"` as it is.

So the result needs to be 
`abc def "<def>"`

Comment: Can you please elaborate : replace what by what?

Comment: Could you give us an example of what the output should be?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 'abc <abc> def "<def>"
```

To replace `<abc>` with `REPLACE_WITH`:

```
b = a.sub(/(?<!")<[^>]*>(?!")/,"REPLACE_WITH")
puts b
```

Output:

```
abc REPLACE_WITH def "<def>"
```

To replace `abc` in `<abc>` with `REPLACE_WITH`:

```
b = a.sub(/(?<!"<)(?<=<)[^>]*(?=>)(?!>")/,"REPLACE_WITH")
puts b
```

Output:

```
abc <REPLACE_WITH>  def "<def>"
```

If you want to replace globally (not only first appearance), then use `gsub` instead of `sub`.

I don't know Ruby. This syntax is just that I learned from looking at other answers to use regex in Ruby. So, I am not sure if syntax is correct or not.

Comment: Thank you for hints, and I worked out the pattern I need. `pattern = /(?<!")\<.*?\>(?!")/`, just in case anyone need.